# Automate the opening recording and closing a text file for serial data with minicom (and arduino)

Tags: bash, io, serial-port, minicom

I am using an arduino and save the output with minicom but want to automate the process for opening recording and closing the text file.

I am currently using the following: first I give the following command in the terminal:

```
$ minicom -D /dev/cu.usbserial-1420 -b 115200
```

Then for the opening recording and closing of the text file: have to do the following:

- Press Ctrl A + Z
- Press Shift + L for start recording
- Waiting for writing output
- Press Shift + L for stop recording
- Check file minicom.cap – it’s a text file and you can open using any text editor

which is a bit cumbersome

Instead what I want to do is to write a bash script (.sh or .zsh) which would look like this:

```
# Command number 1 to be implemented which open a text file and start writing the output
sleep 2 #(peforms the recording during 2 seconds)
# Command number 2 to be implemented which stops the writing and close the file
```

Comment: `Ctrl-A Z` should show the help screen of minicom, or is it something else?

Comment: thank you for the comment @Fravadona. But this is the point: you are referring to GUI of minicom. I would like to have a more automated way of doing things and do everything from the command line (in a bash script) and not having to rely on `Ctrl-A Z` + some other commands

Answer (score 1):

`minicom` doesn't seem easy to automate. If you only use it for setting the baud rate and recording the output during 2 seconds then you might replace it with something like:

```bash
stty -F /dev/cu.usbserial-1420 115200

cat /dev/cu.usbserial-1420 > output.cap &

sleep 2

kill %
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Fravadona. That helps a lot. I upvoted your question (although I cannot accept it as I formulate the question with minicom). I am on mac OS and hat to change the `-F` in `-f` but it works fine. However the bash script seems to be hanging and I have to actively terminate the task with `Ctrl + c` while recording. Any idea why?

Comment: @ecjb My bad, when the `sleep` completes the `cat` isn't affected because it doesn't read from stdin. I fixed my answer